# jQuery select2 plugin - how to select repeated items. Clear explanation below

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery select2 plugin. In this plugin is there any option to select items which are already selected. Suppose in my application to search countries, i am using select2 plugin. Once i select a country named "Australia", i should be able to select "Australia" again. I have gone through the documentation, but i couldn't get anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Why would you want to select something which has already been selected? Are you talking about the multi-select box?

Comment: Please don't delete and recreate your questions. Please edit them instead. The question is still confusing; what do you mean by selecting it *again* if it's already selected?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954592/jquery-select2-select-same-option-multiple-times