# How to select one option multiple times from jquery,js or html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm stuck with multiple select options where I want to select particular options multiple times I read select2 doc I don't get the result please help me out

```
<select id="exppicker" name="experience[]" data-size="6" data-max-options="5"
                                        class="form-control"  data-live-search="true">
                                        <option class="option">Activity</option>
                                        <option class="option">Adventure</option>
                                        <option class="option">Coffee/Tea</option>
                                        <option class="option">Food</option>
                                        <option class="option">Bar</option>
                                        <option class="option">Movies</option>
                                        <option class="option">Museums</option>
                                        <option class="option">Crafts</option>
                                    </select>
```

This is my Select box where I want to select the Activity option multiple times.

Comment: You can't. What you could do, is to add an extra "Select target" option at the top of the list. When user selects an option, just register it, and reset the select element to the top option. If you want to see the user select, show it in a separate element, or change the text shown in the top option.

Comment: I think this could be a kind of backup plan, but it's not exactly the best solution

Comment: You could try to listen clicks on the select element. Then check `event.target`. If the target is the select element itself, then the list was opened, if the target is an option element, then user clicked on an option, and you can do what ever you need with the (already) selected value. Not sure how well this works in mobile environments, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26061946/12196329

Comment: I made [a snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/7mz5Lyku/1/) based on the idea introduced in my second comment. It works fine on a desktop, but, as I already suspected, it doesn't work at all in mobile environments.

Comment: Give that in ans section if it is working..

Comment: In a modern world it's hard to imagine a web page not working in a mobile environment, hence the answer wouldn't be particularly useful. If you really want such a feature, you should take a look at other Bootstrap alternatives for creating a select picker without the native select element, and apply the snippet to that picker.

Answer (score 0):

"Select target" option at the top of the list. When the user selects an option, just register it, and reset the select element to the top option. If you want to see the user select, show it in a separate element, or change the text shown in the top option. The only ans I got.